# Removing last number in Varchar with Join SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

So I am currently doing an inner join between two tables but the problem I am running into is that there is mismatching data:

```
Table 1                       Table 2

1762320066868                 17623200668681
```

So basically, table 1 has the correct data but table 2 produces an extra an extra number which is a one.

my code is:

```
and table1.primarydocnbr = table2.primarydocnbr
```

how can i change it so table2 is drops the extra 1 at the end?

Comment: Is it possible to fix the data? If so, that would be a better path.

Answer (score 1):

If the `primarydocnbr` are fixed then you can use `left()` :

```
and table1.primarydocnbr = left(table2.primarydocnbr, 13)
```

You can also use `len()` instead of fixed values :

```
and table1.primarydocnbr = left(table2.primarydocnbr, len(table1.primarydocnbr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `SUBSTRING()`

```
and table1.primarydocnbr = SUBSTRING(table2.primarydocnbr, 1, 13)
```

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_substring.asp